# Can I reintegrate from working copy?

Tags: svn, svn-merge-reintegrate

I have trunk and branch codebases in the repository and locally.

Currently I was testing on local branch and when testing was ok I reintegrated branch from repository into local trunk.

Now I was told that before reintegrate I need to do synch from trunk to the branch.

Can I reintegrate from local branch into local trunk or I have to commit after sync into branch in repository and then do reintegrate?

I believe that I can do 'local' reintegrate but I am not 100% sure if this is safe.

Using: **Subversion command-line client, version 1.7.8.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to commit the update coming from trunk to your local copy of branch back to the branch in SVN first. Then you reintegrate from this repo to your local copy of trunk which you then commit once you are satisfied with it.

Yes, it is confusing.

Comment: Does it mean no? Why do I have to commit first? Why cannot I reintegrate from local branch? I cannot see any difference between my local branch and branch in remore repository after committing. That's why I asked.

Comment: I see no reason why you could not in principle but it does not appear to be supported.

Comment: When I try 'reintegrate' from local copy I get `svn: E195002: A working copy merge source needs an explicit revision`